# Where to use exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have an MVC controller that uses a payment service class. Where should I do the exception handling? What is best practice?

Do I use try/catch blocks in both my controller and service class?
Is the exception just thrown again in the service class so it can be handled in the controller? Or should all the exception handling be done in the controller?
I can catch Stripe specific exceptions, should that be done in the service class or controller? Confused...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(MyViewModel model)
{    
    try
    {
        await _paymentService.UpdateSomethingAsync(id, token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle
    }
    enter code here    
}
```

---

```
public class PaymentService : IPaymentService
{   
    public async Task UpdateSomethingAsync(string id, string token)
    {
        try
        {
            //update using Stripe...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Implement error handling
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is by far too broad, as it can´t be simply answered. There are so many factors to consider here, that it´s impossible to put them all into a single short answer. Instead have a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling

Comment: Normally, a uncauthexception (action) filter is used to log exceptions.

Comment: Ok, considering that I have a payment service that uses Stripe. Should I catch the exceptions in my payment service and throw again. Or can I just catch in the controller. ie no try/catch in the payment service, just in controller?

Comment: I think the strategy for your case depends on what you want to accomplish with the exceptions and how you want to return responses client. If you need to log anything in particular that doesn't necessarily affect the response to the user, I think you could do that within the service itself and then throw it to be caught by an outer catch. Then within the outer catch add/format the information you need to log there and return an appropriate response to the client. Note that encapsulating in try-catch and logging affects performance, so as @HimBromBeere says, there is no simple answer to this.

Comment: Generally you only catch an exception if you intend to do something with it, and you catch it at the point where you intend to take the action. Keep those two simple rules in mind and you'll pretty quickly work out the right place to catch any particular exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess exception handling must be at service level as it should be self capable of catching and handling all the exceptions(also, to log it at service level for later analysis) occurred at service level and throwing it in its original form (or as per the need it can be customized at service level) to the receiver.

Receiver (controller in this case) should have it's own error handling mechanism as it is a different layer of application and may require some manipulation over exceptions or it's logging at UI level. Here, note that if there is no manipulation or logging of exception or error is required you can directly show service level exception and remove catch from controller.

Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

just write the same code in catch which is in try{ } because catch never pass back or return the value .

```
   try
        {
            cust_id = txtID.Text;
            submit changes();
            lblmessage.Text = "Data Save";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              lblmessage.Text = "Saving error";
              cust_id = txtID.Text;
              submit changes();

        }
```